# Websphere Liberty server can't load WebTrustAssociationFailedException in custom TAI

Tags: java, security, websphere, single-sign-on, websphere-liberty

I am building a Trust Association Interceptor (TAI) for a Websphere Liberty server that implements OAuth2. It is working well, except that when I encounter an error and throw WebTrustAssociationFailedException, I get an error like the following in the server log:

```
[4/17/15 15:26:55:523 CDT] 000000b1 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.internal.TAIAuthenticator   E CWWKS9107E: Trust Association Init is unable to load Trust Association class com.ibm.websphere.security.WebTrustAssociationFailedException: called with invalid state param
    at com.ibm.tivoli.monitoring.OAuthTai.OAuthTAI.getBearerToken(OAuthTAI.java:299)
    at com.ibm.tivoli.monitoring.OAuthTai.OAuthTAI.negotiateValidateandEstablishTrust(OAuthTAI.java:420)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.internal.TAIAuthenticator.authenticate(TAIAuthenticator.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAuthenticatorProxy.handleTAI(WebAuthenticatorProxy.java:163)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAuthenticatorProxy.authenticate(WebAuthenticatorProxy.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.authenticateRequest(WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.java:724)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.determineWebReply(WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.java:567)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.performSecurityChecks(WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.java:438)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.preInvoke(WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl.java:389)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.collaborator.CollaboratorHelper.preInvokeCollaborators(CollaboratorHelper.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.collaborator.CollaboratorHelperImpl.preInvokeCollaborators(CollaboratorHelperImpl.java:267)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1026)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4499)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795)
```

The message "called with invalid state param" seen in the error above is the message that I provided when throwing the exception.

I'm not understanding why this class is not found. During build I get this class from com.ibm.ws.webcontainer_1.0.1.jar. I would have thought the server would already have this built in.  My server.xml is enabled for it with:

```
<feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
```

But given that it didn't find it, I added this jar to my library on the server so it could get it from there, but this makes no difference.  I still get the above error when throwing this exception. Since it's part of the defined TAI interface, and other classes in the interface like TAIResult cause no problem, I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a simple case of a bad error message. It appears to be saying that the `WebTrustAssociationFailedException` class was not found, but this is not the case. It actually is just reporting that the exception was thrown. The Websphere team has an internal defect to correct the message, and it will be fixed in a future release. For now it can safely be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to protect your application with Java EE security and create TAI that would intercept call to this app, and create TAIResult based on passed token with user id using:

public static TAIResult create(int status, String principal);

This will find a principal user in WAS registry, authenticate it and create LTPA token.

You certainly don't want or need to pass credentials (e.g. password) to WebSphere; the TAI process has no need of an actual password - the very nature of the framework is to allow trust relationships via alternate means.

Additionally - there's also no pressing need to roll your own TAI class and associated proprietary SSO protocol (token, encryption, etc).

WebSphere 7+ ships with both OAuth and SAML TAIs out of the box (though configuration is required to set them up). This gives you two open standard specifications to choose from. You end up writing no code on the WebSphere side. These SSO protocols are widely adopted and mature - vetted by an entire industry of web developers, with few or no attack vectors if implemented properly. DNS or domain alignment is also not necessary with these approaches - they are designed to work across domains.

Comment: Thanks Sandhya. However, I can't use the stock TAI because we require some custom behavior. So I'm really just trying to get to the bottom of why the exception class is not recognized.